# Plupload with C# - Events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, plupload

I am newish to events, and new to flash. I have managed to get files uploaded to my folder using Plupload. I am using a generic handler (New to that too!)

Here's my code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url(/plupload/js/jquery.plupload.queue/css/jquery.plupload.queue.css);
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bp.yahooapis.com/2.4.21/browserplus-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/plupload.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plupload/js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
            url: '/uploader.ashx',
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,
            preinit: attachCallbacks,
            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            //resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },
            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [
                { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
                { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
            ],
            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: '/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: '/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
        });

        // Client side form validation
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();
            // Validate number of uploaded files
            if (uploader.total.uploaded == 0) {
                // Files in queue upload them first
                if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                    // When all files are uploaded submit form
                    uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function () {
                        if (uploader.total.uploaded == uploader.files.length)
                            $('form').submit();
                    });
                    uploader.start();
                } else
                    alert('You must at least upload one file.');
                e.preventDefault();
            }


        function attachCallbacks(Uploader) {

        Uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(Up, File, Response) {
            if ((Uploader.total.uploaded + 1) == Uploader.files.length) {
                window.location = '/display.aspx';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And then in my code, my handler:

```
public class uploader : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int chunk = context.Request["chunk"] != null ? int.Parse(context.Request["chunk"]) : 0;
            string fileName = context.Request["name"] ?? string.Empty;

            HttpPostedFile fileUpload = context.Request.Files[0];

            var uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath(GlobalVariables.UploadPath);
            using (
                var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName),
                                        chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
                fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Success");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

This is working 100%

Problem is, when it complete the upload, nothing happens. It displayed the fact that the files were uploaded.

I need to somehow tell a new method to fire. That is, I need to process the uploaded files. Move them to the right folder ... name them better ... add them to a database, and maybe redirect to the display screen.

So, I need the flash control to tell my code to do something (An event) and also, tell my code which files it can now process (The list of files uploaded).

Is this possible?

Edit: I added the attachCallbacks method, and it's attached. It now redirects to a page, but I need to it somehow send the list of files uploaded to a method (generic handler maybe?) and process the files. How do I redirect to a method?

Answer (score 0):

```
........
uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function () {
    if (uploader.total.uploaded == uploader.files.length)
    $('form').submit();
});

uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function (up, files) {
    //files are uploaded, call script for each file...etc
});


uploader.start();
..........
```

Comment: Thanks - I updated my question with some progress I made. I basically redirect to a new page on completion, and it works, but somehow, I need to redirect to a method, which accepts a list of the files uploaded, so that I can basically foreach through them, and process them one by one in my .Net code. Could you assist? Maybe you answer does, but I'm unable to see how to get the .Net code called.

Comment: The addition is the new attachCallbacks method, and the preinit property.